# Создание кнопок на чистом JS для вывода в input с помощью массива

Tags: javascript

Я сделал массив кнопок, но при нажатии на любую кнопку выводит только 0 (то есть, конечное значение в массиве),
получается я сделал массив для одной кнопки, как это исправить?

```js
const input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'text';
document.body.append(input);

function printBtn() {
    var listBrand = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"];
  
    for (var i = 0; i < listBrand.length; i++) {
        var btn__1 = document.createElement("button");
        var t = document.createTextNode(listBrand[i]);
        btn__1.appendChild(t);
        document.body.appendChild(btn__1);

        btn__1.addEventListener('click', () => {
            input.value += btn__1.innerText;
            all = input.value.split('');
            console.log(all);
        });
    }
}

printBtn();
```

Answer (score 2):

Надо написать не

```
var btn__1 = document.createElement("button");
```

а

```
let btn__1 = document.createElement("button");
```

А лучше уже давным давно забыть про `var`.

И почитать отличие `var`, `let`, `const`

Comment: какая разница? var это глобальная переменная, я кнш мог написать let так нет разницы потому что вызвать btn и t за функции и за циклом мне было не к чему

Comment: ааааааа блин какой я глупый var она в циклах странно работает

Comment: *"я кнш мог написать let так нет разницы"* --- как видим, **разница есть**.  Всё же рекомендую и почитать отличия  и в принципе от `var` отказаться (если только использовать в местах где это необходимо, зная различия в поведении и это будет уместно)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'text';
document.body.append(input);

function printBtn() {
    let listBrand = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"];
  
    for (let i = 0; i < listBrand.length; i++) {
        let btn__1 = document.createElement("button");
        let t = document.createTextNode(listBrand[i]);
        btn__1.appendChild(t);
        document.body.appendChild(btn__1);

        btn__1.addEventListener('click', () => {
            input.value += btn__1.innerText;
            all = input.value.split('');
            console.log(all);
        });
    }
}

printBtn();
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: не знаю, уместна ли моя правка